# android share image + AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hello I am new in android and I need to share Image using Share Intent. For that I use following AsyncTask.

```
public class ShareImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String image_url;
    URL myFileUrl;

    String myFileUrl1;
    Bitmap bmImg = null;
    Intent share;
    File file;

    public ShareImageTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading Image ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            myFileUrl = new URL(args[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            String path = myFileUrl.getPath();
            String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/Google Image Wallpaper/");
            dir.mkdirs();
            String fileName = idStr;
            file = new File(dir, fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmImg.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pDialog.dismiss();
        share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");

        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, file);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

    }

}
```

Now I have to call this ShareImageTask by passing image URL. But I dont know how to call this ???

For example :-

```
String Imageurl="my imageurl";
new ShareImageTask(Imageurl).execute();
```

Comment: your are getting any error when starting ShareImageTask as in given example?

Comment: Code is almost fine, what an issue ??

Comment: @CapDroid How to call that AsyncTask????

Comment: you already wrote in question. **new ShareImageTask(Imageurl).execute();**, is it not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call `ShareImageTask` as:

```
String Imageurl="my imageurl";
new ShareImageTask(Curent_Activity.this).execute(Imageurl);
```

and change your In `onPostExecute` code as :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pDialog.dismiss();
    share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");

    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath().toString()));

    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

}
```

Comment: Uri.parse(file) give me error.. The method parse(String) in the type Uri is not applicable for the arguments (File)

Comment: @Monika : sorry i miss it just pass path of file in Uri.parse see my edit answer

Comment: when i select perticular share item for example "whats app" it is not send that image. I think i cant get path perfectly. Please help me.

Comment: @Monika : then just debug app. just put log inside onPostExecute and check your are getting file path or not

Comment: @Monika : place log in onPostExecute and doInBackground and check file is creating or not like `System.out.println("File path ::"+file.getAbsolutePath().toString());` and check your log

Comment: @HJV : how you known it's not launching application createChooser dialog ?

Comment: it launching but after selecting perticular one image is not send.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21432/discussion-between-monika-and--k)

Answer (score 0):

Change your AsyncTask constructor to like this

```
public ShareImageTask(Context context,String image_url) {
        this.context = context;
        this.image_url = image_url;
}
```

So, you can call like this

```
String Imageurl="my imageurl";
new ShareImageTask(getApplicationContext(),Imageurl).execute();
```

Comment: i'm not able to see ShareImageTask constructor who take two params?

Comment: This way is work but after progress dialog "downloading image.." Share intent is open but when i select particular it not open for example when i select whats app dialog disappear and "Share a file fail please try again later" toast is display.

Comment: It's still possible, isn't it ? AsyncTask constructor with two params. I always take param for AsyncTask through constructor. Kind of my coding habit. Sorry if that bother you :D.

Comment: Try put context in front of startActivity

Answer (score 0):

Simply do like this..

```
ShareImageTask task = new ShareImageTask();
task.execute(Imageurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change some in your code..

your wrote like this

```
new ShareImageTask(Imageurl).execute();
```

but you have to write like this

```
new ShareImageTask(getApplicationContext()).execute(Imageurl);
```

your creat constructor only with `Context` parameter so you just have to pass only Context when you intilize `ShareImageTask class`

like as below code:

**Class define:**

```
public ShareImageTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
```

**Class initilize;**

```
new ShareImageTask(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: This way is work but after progress dialog "downloading image.." Share intent is open but when i select particular it not open for example when i select whats app then dialog disappear and "Share a file fail please try again later" toast is display.